# Can a Ghanaian receive an emergency UK visa to visit a funeral in London?

Tags: visas, uk, ghanaian-citizens

I'm a Swedish national. My husband is a Ghanaian citizen and has permanent residence in Sweden. My sister-in-law just passed away, and we want to attend her funeral in London.

We plan to stay from 20 March to 24 March 2024 (5 days). What sort of documents would my husband need?

Answer (score 16):

The UK doesn’t have an ‘emergency visa’ as such. Your husband’s Swedish residence makes no difference as to what documents he needs to [visit the UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). You could however choose to use the [Priority application service](https://www.gov.uk/faster-decision-visa-settlement) but it’s expensive.

Comment: I had used the priority service. I had got the visa in exactly 5 days. If there is nothing else, its straight forward. The documents needed will be downloadable as a checklist when you apply for visa.

Comment: His Swedish residence might make a difference in his chances to get the visa.